# wp8 put all photos of listbox to one photo

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox, photo

hiii
i have a listbox in my app every row content of some photos what i want is to put all those  photos in my listbox to one photo to apply share it on facebook 
i want to put my photos in listbox with the same order to one photo to make me able to share it to facebook or twitter

### and this is my nested listbox

```
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>



                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>


                </ItemsPanelTemplate>


            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >


                        <!--<TextBlock Padding="3,0,3,0"
                  Text="{Binding}" Foreground="DarkRed" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}"/>-->
                        <ListBox x:Name="phoronic_son" ItemsSource="{Binding}"   Foreground="Black"  Margin="82,228,71,209" >
                            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>

                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>



                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>


                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>


                            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <!--<TextBlock Padding="3,0,3,0"
                  Text="{Binding StringFormat='{}{0}.jpg'}" Foreground="DarkRed" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}"/>-->
                                    <Image Source="{Binding StringFormat='{}{0}.jpg'}" Height="80" Width="80"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>


                        </ListBox>


                    </StackPanel>

                </DataTemplate>


            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

        </ListBox>
```

Comment: Interpunction please...

Comment: Do you want the picture captured to look like the listbox on-screen, or do you want it to have some other format? Can you show a link of what you want the composite image to look like?

Comment: i want to convetr my listbox to image (every row in my listbox content alot of images) i want to conert my listbox to one image